# image rendering in PyScript

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, image-processing, pyscript

after doing lots of research I managed to make Matplotlib and OpenCV work on Py-Script but Matplotlib doesn't render the result. It doesn't show the final, gray scaled image.

I have this code here :

```
<py-script>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
row, col = 1, 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(row, col, figsize=(15, 10))
fig.tight_layout()
 
axs[0].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
axs[0].set_title('Original')

axs[1].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(gray_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
axs[1].set_title('Grayscale')

plt.show()
</py-script>
```

and these are my python env and configurations.

```
  <py-env>
    - matplotlib
    - numpy
    - opencv-python
    - paths:
      - /1.jpg
  </py-env>


  <py-config>
    - autoclose_loader: true
    - runtimes:
      -
        src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/dev/full/pyodide.js"
        name: pyodide-0.20
        lang: python
  </py-config>
```

in console according what I see, there is no problem. but it doesn't show any image.
the code itself designed to grayscale the photo.
console log of browser:

[image: console log of browser]

Comment: Try replacing `plt.show()` with `fig`

Comment: @Tranbi wow ! thank you so much. it worked ! can you explain what `fig` is ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the matter but as I understand it `plt.show()` tries to open figures in windows. Since you don't have a gui in pyscript, it doesn't work. However it is able to render the returned `fig` directly.

Comment: @Tranbi oh. I understood. thank you. I would give an upvote to your comment but the button doesn't appear. I don't know. maybe stack overflow changed it.

Comment: Porbably not enough rep. Just upvoted your question so that you reach the 15 threshold ;-)

Comment: @Tranbi yes. now I can upvote. thank you again

Comment: @Tranbi, would you please have a look at his question too? i m just trying to import xgboost, but it won't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214163/how-to-import-xgboost-and-time-into-pyscript-web-app?noredirect=1#comment129303834_73214163

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tranbi. if you replace `plt.show()` with `fig` it will work