# How to import xgboost and time into pyscript web app?

Tags: python, time, web-applications, xgboost, pyscript

I am building a web app with pyscript and will use xgboost and time in it. I have successfully loaded pandas, NumPy, and scikit-learn into py-env, and then import those libraries into py-script.

However, when I add xgboost and time into py-env, the web app is stuck in the initiating status and keeps showing

> Loading runtime...
>
> Runtime created...
>
> Initializing components...

So how should I import these 2 libraries into py-scirpt?

Comment: Open the browser debugger. In the Console tab, you will find the error messages. Add those to your question. I wrote an article on PyScript debugging and error management strategies: https://www.jhanley.com/pyscript-debugging-and-error-management-strategies/

Comment: `ValueError: Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'xgboost'. You can use micropip.install(..., keep_going=True) to get a list of all packages with missing wheels.`
So what should I do now?

Comment: That package is not compatible.